# Can somebody explain this Android-Kotlin code? Please

Tags: android, kotlin, syntax, bluetooth-lowenergy

i am new to Android development with Kotlin pogramming language, i am not able to understand this code below,
what i am guessing is that an instance(scanResultAdapter) is created from ScanResultAdapter class, this class has the code for recyclerView adapter.
This code is in MainActivity.kt file in punchThrough's article about BLE -

```
private val scanResultAdapter: ScanResultAdapter by lazy {
    ScanResultAdapter(scanResults) { result ->
        // User tapped on a scan result
        if (isScanning) {
            stopBleScan()
        }
        with(result.device) {
            Log.w("ScanResultAdapter", "Connecting to $address")
            connectGatt(context, false, gattCallback)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your answers, sorry my bad, i mistakenly missed some code here.i added it now. Looks like it is a lambda expression as you said, but i have never seen anywhere putting lambda expression while creating object of a class. Because the ScanResultAdapter class is defined in a separate file than this. What's your opinion regarding this guys

Answer (score 1):

Which point you don't understand?

Regards your guess(the logic of code), that's right, I think.

It seems that you are not familiar with Kotlin, you can check them one by one. For an instance, I don't know this style code:

```
ScanResultAdapter(scanResults) { result ->
  ....
}
```

`{ result -> .. }`, I need to know that's the `Lambdas Expressions`
Here's [a reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/kotlin-lambdas-expressions-and-anonymous-functions/)

Maybe I don't understand the `with` of Kotlin, refer to [this document](https://www.kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/with.html) and so on.

Comment: If the function’s last parameter is a function, it can go outside the parentheses. https://antonioleiva.com/lambdas-kotlin-android/

Answer (score 1):

You are right. (scanResults) is the first argument of constructor. Second is callback of click listener in curly brackets. When  user tap on a device in the list this code in braces {} will be executed. Kotlin can take out of parentheses () arguments if it is functions.